# Tutorial ASP.NET Core app not seen by localhost

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Using MS Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 pro to build an ASP.NET Core MVC for the first time. When this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) has me run it, Localhost comes up with some stuff relating to the app (its name, a welcome message).  The tutorial says to then add "/MvcMovie/" to the URL in the address field.  Then, localhost says "No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44379/MvcMovie/".

I'm new at this.  Not sure from the tutorial when/if to actually add something to localhost.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be best if you add your attempts with code snippets, that way one would be able to provide an accurate solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to this:

> In the Configure your new project dialog, enter MvcMovie for Project
> name. It's important to name the project MvcMovie. Capitalization
> needs to match each namespace when code is copied.

The tutorial is saying that your Project's name should be MvcMovie when you create it. Other than that, the tutorial doesn't ask you to go to localhost/mvcMovie. To figure out the routing in an MVC check the next few parts about Controllers-Views-Models. There will be explained about the routing part and how you can access different parts of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The MvcMovie mentioned in the document does not require you to enter in the URl, it is just the name of the created project:

[image]

If you need to use MvcMovie as the routing address in the Url, you can do this:

Controller:

```
 [ApiController]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("MvcMovie")]
        public IActionResult MvcMovie()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View demo:

```
<h1>This is MvcMovie Controller!</h1>
```

Test url:`https://localhost:7040/MvcMovie`

Result:

[image]

I think you need to know the routing rules in mvc, you can read this document:

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0)